# How can I search for a sticker or emoji on Line for Android?

Tags: search, emoticons, line

How can I search for a sticker or emoji  on Line for Android?

On Line for Microsoft Windows I can use::

[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)

Comment: View this link https://drfone.wondershare.com/line/line-sticker.html (except for the VPN part)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thank you, which step explains how to search  for sticker or emoji within Line?

Comment: where it says to click on more, then select the store. Disclaimer: I don't have Line installed on my phones. I could be 100% wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINE for Android provides in-line sticker suggestion when directly typing on the chat input text field.

To enable/disable this feature:

1. Go to **Settings** (the cog-wheel icon on the top-right, this can be accessed on 'Friends' page or 'More' page)
2. Under "Shops", tap **Stickers**
3. Under "Sticker settings", toggle **Display suggestions**

When it is enabled, type a single keyword (e.g. 'work'). The text will be bolded (**work**) and related stickers appear above the chat input. Then tap the sticker to use.

**Note**: since the stickers appear above the chat input, fullscreen keyboards (usually used on landscape layout) may break the feature since the keyboard and the input box will cover the whole screen, including the stickers.

---

Demo:

[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)